# Routing to webpage returns a 404 (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am fairly new to using NodeJS and express so forgive me for any bad syntax. When I try to add routing to the different pages that I have, only the Index ('/') is found and the rest of the pages ('/about', '/code', etc) return a 404.

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var aboutRouter = require('./routes/about');
var coolThingRouter = require('./routes/cool-thing');
var codeRouter = require('./routes/code');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/about', aboutRouter);
app.use('/code', codeRouter);
app.use('/cool-thing', coolThingRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js, routes/code.js, etc.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/code', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('code', { title: 'Code ~ Humble Abode'   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Project Directory

```
public:
  | images
  | javascripts
  | stylesheets
routes:
  | index.js
  | code.js
  | ...
views:
  | code.jade
  | index.jade
  | ...
app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using router like

```
app.use(indexRouter);
```